# Setting up httpd authentication for a particular page

Tags: authentication, apache

I had a script install this all for me but I am trying to configure it to how I like.

The issue is it does it at the root of the web directory I want it to a particular folder in the directory...how would I go about this...

This is what I have now

```
    ServerName localhost
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin admin@rutorrent
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/rutorrent/

    <Directory />
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </Directory>
    <Location />
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "My ruTorrent web site"
        AuthUserFile "/etc/httpd/rutorrent_passwd"
        Require valid-user
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>
    <Location ~ "^/rutorrent/(conf|share)">
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </Location>
    <Location ~ "/\\.svn">
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </Location>
    <Location "/RPC00001">
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "My ruTorrent web site"
        AuthUserFile "/etc/httpd/rutorrent_passwd"
        Require user torrent
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/rutorrent.pem
    ServerAdmin admin@rutorrent
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/rutorrent

    <Directory />
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </Directory>
    <Location />
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "My ruTorrent web site"
        AuthUserFile "/etc/httpd/rutorrent_passwd"
        Require valid-user
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>
    <Location ~ "^/rutorrent/(conf|share)">
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </Location>
    <Location ~ "/\\.svn">
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </Location>
    <Location "/RPC00001">
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "My ruTorrent web site"
        AuthUserFile "/etc/httpd/rutorrent_passwd"
        Require user torrent
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
#SCGIMount /RPC00001 127.0.0.1:23876
```

I want to make it so it asks for a password in /var/rutorrent/passwordarea

I also wouldn't mind having a separate password and username for /var/rutorrent so if someone could share how to do that as well I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Wondering if I didn't ask this correctly...should I clarify something?

Comment: I have figured it out but can't answer it for a few more hours...